# Mismatch Between Json data And Classes i've made

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

im really new to swift and without your help i cant move forward guys

can someone please tell me how can i fix this error?

i put the image of error below

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AppCategory : NSObject {

    var name : String?
    var apps : [App]?
    var type : String?



        override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
            if key == "apps " {
                var apps = [App]()
                for dict in value as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    let app = App()
                    app.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                    apps.append(app)
                }

            }else{
                super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        }
 static func fetchFeaturedApps (completionHandler :  @escaping ([AppCategory]) -> ()) {


        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url:URL(string: "http://www.statsallday.com/appstore/featured")!)

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let json = try( JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)) as! [String : Any]

                    var appCategories = [AppCategory]()

                    for dict in json["categories"] as! [[String:Any]]{
                        let appcategory = AppCategory()
                        appcategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                        appCategories.append(appcategory)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completionHandler(appCategories)
                    }


                }catch let err {
                    print(err)
                }



            }.resume()

        }
```

here is my class

```
class App : NSObject {

    var Id : NSNumber?
    var Name : String?
    var ImageName : String?
    var Category : String?
    var Price : NSNumber?

}
```

[the JSON link](http://www.statsallday.com/appstore/featured)

this is a fuction that should pass back cell but gives me the mismatching on NSArray error

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! AppCell

            cell.apps = appCategory?.apps?[indexPath.item]

        return cell

    }
```

i dont know how to findout which types are not match

Comment: Please include codes and relevant info into your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

for the second error

check this line             `if key == "apps " {`      remove  space in word apps

you should use this

```
 for dict in json["categories"] as! [[String:Any]]{

    }
```

// Any is an alias for any data type.
  //  AnyObject is an alias for any data type derived from a class.

**but better  to write it**

```
guard let categories   = json["categories"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
        return
    }

    for dict in categories {

    }
```

[image]

Comment: now i am getting this error :  fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
(lldb)

Comment: @michealwoods  check  above image you will see all data without any problem, just share where is error

Comment: i edited my post now its more clear thanks for your time

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AppStoreNew.App 0x608000115f00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Price.'   this is new error

Comment: price is double value make sure that you handle it correctly

Comment: in my class as you can see i declared the Double type should i do sth more somewhere else?